# I'm trying to build a production version with yarn then I get this error: Type error: Property 'store' does not exist on type '{}'. How can I resolve?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx-react-lite

So the error is from this Qwerty component,
Giving Error: Property 'store' does not exist on type '{}'

````
```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'


export default observer(function Qwerty({store}) {
  const qwerty = ['qwertyuiop', 'asdfghjkl', 'zxcvbnm']
  return (
    <div>
      {qwerty.map((row) => (
        <div className="flex justify-center">
          {row.split('').map((char) => {
            const bgColor = store.exactGuesses.includes(char)
              ? 'bg-green-400'
              : store.inexactGuesses.includes(char)
              ? 'bg-yellow-400'
              : store.allGuesses.includes(char)
              ? 'bg-gray-400'
              : 'bg-gray-200'
            return (
              <div
                className={`rounded-m m-px flex h-10 w-10 items-center justify-center uppercase ${bgColor}`}
              >
                {char}
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
})
```
````

**The index.tsx page with the store is as follows:**
**It also has the following bug Linted on the 'store' attribute of Qwerty:**
Type '{ store: { word: string; guesses: any[]; currentGuess: number; readonly won: boolean; readonly lost: boolean; readonly allGuesses: any; readonly exactGuesses: any; readonly inexactGuesses: any; init(): void; submitGuess(): void; handleKeyup(e: any): any; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & object'.
Property 'store' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & object'.ts(2332)

````
```
import { observer, useLocalObservable } from 'mobx-react-lite'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import Guess from '../components/Guess'
import Qwerty from '../components/Qwerty'
import PuzzleStore from '../stores/PuzzleStore'

export default observer(function Home() {
  const store = useLocalObservable(() => PuzzleStore)
  useEffect(() => {
    store.init()
    window.addEventListener('keyup', store.handleKeyup)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', store.handleKeyup)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen w-screen flex-col items-center justify-center bg-gray-600">
      <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold uppercase text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-br from-blue-400 to-green-400">Wordle
      </h1>
      {store.guesses.map((_, i) => (
        <Guess 
        key={i}
        word={store.word} 
        guess={store.guesses[i]} 
        isGuessed={i < store.currentGuess}/>
      ))}
      {store.won && <h1>You won!</h1>}
      {store.lost && <h1>You lost!</h1>}
      {(store.won || store.lost) && (<button onClick={store.init}>Play Again</button>)}
      <Qwerty store={store}/>
      word: {store.word} <br/>
      guesses: {JSON.stringify(store.guesses)}
    </div>
  )
})
```
````

Comment: You must type your props add `{ store }: MyStoreType` you can even use any temporarily

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to include the store type, thanks to Vincent

```
export default observer(function Qwerty({store}:any)
```